# Show block and template from other extension

Tags: template, blocks, layout

I'm having some troubles in showing one simple block from other model.

I have these extensions:

Extension 1: /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/[module]_1/

Extension 2: /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/[module]_2/

I want to show one block from [module]_1 in [module]_2.

I already put some code in [module]_2 .xml file:

```
<block type="[module]_1/onepage_pickmeshops_dropdown" name="[module]_1.pickmeshops.dropdown" as="pickme" template="[module]_1/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/pickmeshopsdropdown.phtml"/>
```

And added this code where i want to display the info:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('pickme') ?>
```

But after all i can't see what i want to see..

---

Update:

Here is my module 2 .xml:

```
<block type="checkout/onepage_review" name="checkout.onepage.review" as="review" template="onepagecheckout/onepage/review.phtml">
                    <block type="checkout/cart_coupon" name="checkout.cart.coupon" as="coupon" template="onepagecheckout/onepage/coupon.phtml"/>
                    <block type="onepagecheckout/agreements" name="checkout.onepage.agreements" as="agreements" template="onepagecheckout/onepage/agreements.phtml"/>
                    <block type="core/template" name="chronopost.pickmeshops.dropdown" as="pickme" template="chronopost_shipping/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/pickmeshopsdropdown.phtml"/>
                    <block type="checkout/onepage_review_info" name="info" template="onepagecheckout/onepage/review/info.phtml">
                        <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>onepagecheckout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
                        <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>onepagecheckout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
                        <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>onepagecheckout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
                        <block type="checkout/cart_totals" name="checkout.onepage.review.info.totals" as="totals" template="onepagecheckout/onepage/review/totals.phtml"/>
                        <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.onepage.review.info.items.before" as="items_before"/>
                    </block>
                </block>
```

And a little more info:

```
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('agreements') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('pickme') ?> 
            <?php if (Mage::helper('onepagecheckout')->isSubscribeNewAllowed()) : ?> 
        <p class="newsletter">
            <input type="checkbox" id="newsletter-signup" name="newsletter" value="1" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('newsletter')->__('Sign up for our newsletter') ?>" class="checkbox" />
            <label for="newsletter-signup">
                <?php echo Mage::helper('newsletter')->__('Sign up for our newsletter') ?>
            </label>
        </p>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: You can call your block inside local.xml and try. This link may help for that. http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/5-useful-tricks-for-your-magento-local-xml/

Answer (score 1):

Some basic steps to go through

- Check that caching and the compiler are turned of
- Double check if the file exists and you got the path right (might be a small typo, who knows)
- replace the `type` with `core/template`, if there's an issue with your block class this will prevent the template from showing up
- Make sure the parent block is the right file, turn on *template path hints* to check this.

One of the above should turn up something useful nine out of ten times.

Comment: Hi Sander, i have cache turned on but i already turned off and still no changes...

Comment: keep it turned off while developing. It works much easier. Did any of the other suggestions help?

Comment: I tried everything but block still doesn't show.

Comment: Please update your question with more of the layout xml please

Comment: Do you mean module2 layout?

Comment: the part where you actually add module1 block inside module2 block. So whats around the XML part you've already posted

Comment: I already added more information. Thank you!

Comment: looks alright as far as I can see. Are you sure that the XML is being picked up by Magento? Also make sure the `pickmeshopsdropdown.phtm` doesn't contain any php errors

Comment: Yeah because i can see "agreements" and "newsletter" loading fine. And pickmeshopsdropdown.phtm have no errors.. So it's a quite strange.

Comment: since agreements and newsletter are default Magento they would be there even tho the XML wasn't picked up.
Replace the `checkout.onepage.agreements` block with `<remove name="checkout.onepage.agreements"/>` to see what happens. If the agreements are no longer shown the XMl is picked up.
Also, try and add your block using the `local.xml`. This XML is surely used by Magento and not overwritten.